# Implementing Full Text Search in Analysis Services Cube

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, ssas, sql-server-2012

I'm creating an SSAS cube (SQL 2012), one of the purposes of which is to expose data to a .NET UI which contains a number of filters/search features, allowing users to query the data.  In the existing SQL Server DB, we make use of Full Text Search to help with text-based filters/searches.

I've looked around for more information about implementing FTS on an SSAS cube, specifically to search Dimension members and filter by Measure values but it seems to be very thin on the ground.

Can FTS be implemented on an SSAS cube?  If so, is it recommended or is there a better way of achieving this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box support for Full Text Search in the sense that dimension members and measure values are indexed to support FTS. Generally speaking, filters are applied at query time. There are several ways to do this with MDX with varying degrees of impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

Best approach to organize members in a dimension is to arrange them in hierarchies.

What you can also so is search a attribute using a MDX. Maybe you can display a search field on your application and based on the imputed values, run the MDX query on the dimension